# Options to replace a non standard size window on a budget

Tags: windows

I have been slowly replacing windows in my home. I’m on to one which is a sliding window measuring 56”w x 36”h. The rough opening is 56.75x37.5” and the builder shimmed with 1x4s. I am posting to see if anyone has good advice as this is a non standard window size and the only one in the house. I’d rather not make the window smaller which seems like the easiest option.

Comment: What type of window is going in? Wood/Aluminium/Plastic, single/double glazed. Will it remain sliding/fixed/on hinges. You can easily make your own wooden frame and buy glass, stick it in - done, for any size fixed window; with a tiny bit of effort you can make it open on hinges.

Comment: Interesting idea. Initially, I was thinking it would be a vinyl sliding double pane window. They are pretty costly to order custom. To mode to standard sizing I could increase the opening to 60 inch which is a bit difficult or go all the way down to 48. The latter is easy but takes away a lot of window.

Comment: Check with other manufacturers, perhaps? I have a 57x39 that was a stock size (Marvin) if you could make the opening a bit taller rather than wider. They claim to want more rough opening than you have, but in fact the window itself would fit in a 56-3/4 wide hole with room to spare. Just make sure the hole isn't too crooked, which is where all that extra slop they request comes into play. That's fixed and could be had as an awning, not a slider.

Comment: Looking quickly at current product, I see a "glider" stock size of 54-1/2 x 36 which is a lot less  reduction than 48" wide if you want a glider/slider particularly. And I have not looked more than quickly, so there may be better/closer options out there, as stock.